# Dia export resolution too small

Tags: dia

I am trying to export a diagram to a format I can load into a wiki tool called 'confluence'. 
The resolution of any export format or even the .dia save file is so small, that when I insert the image it is too small to be seen. When I try to enlarge it, it is blurry.

How do I increase the resolution of Dia save files or Dia exports?

Version: 0.97.2

Comment: what version of dia are you using?

Comment: Same problem here using the same version (from the Ubuntu repositories).

Comment: Related inforamation at: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=535179

Answer (score 29):

This depends a little on the export formats. For some (e.g. PNG antialiased) you can specify a resolution in pixels.
For other formats, go to File->Page Setup... and increase the scale factor.

Comment: On Ubuntu with Dia version 0.97.2, increasing the scale factor in File->Page Setup... fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 26):

On export, **specify the PNG (anti-aliased) (*.png) exporter**. When you click Save, it will ask you for the resolution. Change either the X or Y, and it will scale up the other so your image is not distored. Do not use the Cairo or Pixbuf exporters, as they do not ask you.

To specify the PNG exporter, select File->Export, and at the bottom of the Export Diagram dialog is a section Export Options and the drop down to list the available exporters.

Comment: This still has a low DPI. I can't change this.

Answer (score 3):

Check menu "File" -> "Layout" 
Then check the scale is set to 1 (do not set the sheets)

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the .svg format for me. It is a web-standard and a wiki software should definitely provide loading such files. It's VECTORBASED. That's great! Now, it's even supported by Microsoft Word to paste in such a .svg file. Compare it with PDF, but it's even more light-weighed as to what disk usage is concerned. You can embedd it at many places.

Comment: Yes, together with other tools like Inkscape, this may resolve the original question.